# how to define dummy variable value by pass by reference in php

Tags: php

```
$smarty->assign_by_ref('global_plugin_menu', $dummy = null);
```

Showing this error when i try to run above line:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: Save the value in a variable.  Pass that variable as a parameter.  You are doing `$dummy = null`.  That's an expression.  It's ran, then its return value (which is the set value) is passed as the parameter.  It wants a variable, not a value.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need to do this, but:

```
$dummy = null;
$smarty->assign_by_ref('global_plugin_menu', $dummy);
```